# Aligning data values vertically in JFreeChart bar chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have displayed values on top of bars in a JFreeChart bar chart. If there are lot of bars, values are getting too congested if the label is horizontal. I need to display the values vertically. I tried below options but they didn't work:

```
ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
    ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE1, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+90.0);

ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
    ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE1, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+45.0);

ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
    ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+45.0);
```

Any help on this very much appreciated.

[image]

I tried with Radians and below options. The maximum I was able to rotate is as below

```
ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE6, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,-Math.PI/2);

    ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE7, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,-Math.PI*2);
 ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE8, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,Math.PI/2);

    ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE9, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+270.0);
 ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE10, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+360.0);

    ItemLabelPosition itemLabelPositionTwo=new ItemLabelPosition(
        ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE1, TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,TextAnchor.BASELINE_RIGHT,+Math.PI/2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The relevant [`ItemLabelPosition`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/ItemLabelPosition.html) constructor expects the `angle` in *radians*; you probably want something like this:

```
ItemLabelPosition itemlabelposition = new ItemLabelPosition(
    ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER, -Math.PI / 2);
```

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I tried it. Please see my comment. I have edited my question

Comment: I don't know how you're getting the result pictured; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on the problem; one series should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Convert degrees to Radian and pass the converted value as parameter(angle) for ItemLabelPosition

ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER,TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER,-1.5708); -- here 1.5708(Radian) is for 90°